# Как шифровать данные в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, пароль

Таблица в базе данных (sqlite3) будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
id | date     | text
1  | 1.1.1970 | Blablabla
```

Хочу добавить возможность шифровать данные в БД паролем от пользователя.

Проблемы:

1. Если зашифровать `date`, то нельзя будет сортировать записи по дате создания.
2. Если шифровать `text`, то будут проблемы с поиском.

Как правильно зашифровать записи в базе данных?

**UPD**

Еще вопрос. Допустим пользователь забыл пароль, которым зашифрованы данные. Как грамотно реализовать восстановление пароля?

Просто выслать на почту новый не получится, т.к. он не подойдет для расшифровки.

Comment: А какова цель шифрования ? Гугл по запросу "sqllite шифрование" предлагает различные варианты. И понятное дело, что все они касаются шифрования на диске. при sql запросах если БД была успешно открыта то она видится в обычном виде.

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, не знал об этом. Еще вопрос. Допустим пользователь забыл пароль, которым зашифрованы данные. Как грамотно реализовать восстановление пароля?

Comment: Боюсь это при нормальном шифровании невозможно. Если вы конечно где то отдельно не сохраните шифрованный пароль :) Ну или не будете хранить пароли пользователей на своем защищенном сервере и как то авторизовать пользователей